# Possible to embed PDF files and videos into an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

As the title indicates, I want to know how difficult it would be to create an iOS app in which I can include a few of my own movies and pdf files, and make them viewable from the app itself.

I know iOS has a built in PDF viewer and movie player, just I want to make sure I can access them easily, and will not have to write my own PDF viewer or anything of the sort.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: If so, any pointers on how I should go about doing this? Perhaps a link to a tutorial or something?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For viewing PDF Files you can use the UIWebView or the QuickLook framework (see QLPreviewController class for details).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, entirely possible. you can use `PDF Kit` for pdf affairs [here is the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html)

or video reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Intro/CVProg_Intro.html)

Comment: The Apple kit is only for Mac OS, not iOS.